# How to create a calculation for the start/end date of the previous year, start date of this year in IBM cognos

Tags: cognos-bi

I am running a cognos report and when I am running the report on 2018-07-05 and I want the MTD start date  to be as 2018-06-01 so I am using date function logic as
**"_first_of_month (_add_months (current_date,-1))"** to get MTD start date (previous month start date '2018-06-01') and 
**"_last_of_month (_add_months (current_date,-1))"** to get the MTD end date ( previous month end date '2018-06-30').
Can you help me create the date logic to fetch
YTD start date as  '2018-01-01',
YTD end date as  '2018-06-30',
previous year start date as '2017-01-01' and 
previous year end date as '2017-06-30' and also the logic should work to fetch the december data when the report is ran in january.
Thank you

Comment: Is this to be used in a filter?  Something like [Invoice Date] between 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31?  Are your years really only 6 months long and omit July through December?  Is the Month-to-Date value intended to return all of the previous month (2018-02-01 to 2018-02-28 if I run the report in March)?  Why is it month-to-date rather than simply previous month?

Comment: I'm also confused about the last requirement:  "the logic should work to fetch the december data when the report is ran in january."  Does this mean that if the report is run in January, YTD is defined as all records since December 1st of the previous year?

Comment: I have to use this in the case logic to create a metric as a data item   as  case when cov date is between mtd sd and mtd ed then premium  else 0.No I just took the example of  6 months this I need to create month end report for all 12 months.yes I run the report on first of every month to fetch previous month data. I have to give both start date and end date of month or may be i can use the only month logic too.I want the logic to work even when i run on the first of jan 2018 to get the data of 2017-12-01 to 2017-12-31.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to create a filter...

You can use a macro for this so that the calculation takes place before the database server is contacted.

First of last month

```
[Namespace].[Query Subject].[Query Item] > #timestampMask (_add_months ($current_timestamp, -1), 'yyyy')#-#timestampMask (_add_months ($current_timestamp, -1), 'mm')#-01
```

End of last month

```
[Namespace].[Query Subject].[Query Item] < #timestampMask (_last_of_month (_add_months ($current_timestamp, -1)), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#
```

First of this year

```
[Namespace].[Query Subject].[Query Item] > #timestampMask ($current_timestamp, 'yyyy')#-01-01
```

If you need only display the values on the report, this can be done using a Layout Calculation so that the database server is not involved.  The syntax will be different.

Answer (score 0):

YTD (as of last complete month)

```
(
    extract(month,current_date) > 1 
    AND extract(year,current_date) = extract(year,[Date]) 
    AND [Date] <= _last_of_month(_add_months(current_date,-1))
)
OR
(
    extract(month,current_date) = 1 
    AND extract(year,current_date)-1 = extract(year,[Date])
)
```

LY YTD (as of last complete month)

```
(
    extract (month,current_date) > 1 
    AND extract(year,current_date)-1 = extract(year,[Date]) 
    AND [Date] <= _last_of_month(_add_months(_add_years(current_date,-1),-1))
(
OR 
(
    extract(month,current_date) = 1 
    AND extract(year,current_date)-2 = extract(year,[Date])
)
```

There's only one month we have to contend with; January. If the current month is January, then we simply get all of the previous year for YTD. The same applies for LY YTD, except in that case we get all of the complete year two years ago. Run it in January 2019 and YTD will be everything in 2018 and LY YTD will be everything in 2017.

As for getting the first day of the current year, that's easy:

```
cast(extract(year,current_date) || '-01' || '-01',date)
```

..first day of last year:

```
cast(extract(year,current_date)-1 || '-01' || '-01',date)
```

Comment: As-of today (2018-07-30), your YTD expression returns true if [Date] is between 2017-07-31 and 2018-08-30.  I always think of YTD (year-to-date) as all records since January 1st of this year.

Comment: Thanks you.                                                                                                       Just need to get the First date of the previous year ie 2017-01-01Logic and first date of the present year 2018-01-01.Can any one help?

Comment: I amended my answer to reflect your requirements.

Comment: I dont know why I am getting '0' when I execute this statement extract(year,current_date)-1 || '-01' || '-01' insted of 2017-01-01

Comment: I'm not sure. I tested all of the expressions in Cognos to make sure the syntax was  correct.

Comment: Thank you. I was not casting it thats why it was returing a 0.                                              cast ((extract(year, current_date)-1 ) as  varchar (4))|| '-01-01' this syntax returns a 2017-01-01 as prior year start date.